# How To Obtain Cumulative Sum Array Using Underscore.js?

Tags: underscore.js

I have an `array = [1,2,3,4,5]` and would like to obtain the cumulative sum *array* using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

The result I want is:

```
[1,3,6,10,15]
```

I want the *array* not the cumulative sum 15 as a value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a  [`_.reduce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) to get this:

```js
_.reduce([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (acc, n) { acc.push( (acc.length > 0 ? acc[acc.length-1] : 0) + n); return acc }, [])
```

A more readable version goes here:

```js
var prefixSum = function (arr) {
    var builder = function (acc, n) {
        var lastNum = acc.length > 0 ? acc[acc.length-1] : 0;
        acc.push(lastNum + n);
        return acc;
    };
    return _.reduce(arr, builder, []);
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? For me it returns [1,2,3,4,5] and was similar to the attempt I tried.

Comment: @user664023: Yeah, slight typo. Fixed now, though.

Answer (score 4):

[`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) is also an option:

```js
_.map(array,function(num,i){ if(i > 0) array[i] += array[i-1]; });
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz63M/)

*Note that this edits the original array and is not technically what `_.map` is supposed to do*

If you want a non-destructive version that creates a new array:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var cumulative = 0;
var sums = _.map(array,function(num){ 
    cumulative += num;
    return cumulative;
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgRnC/)

Comment: Good solution but out of curiosity, wouldn't this violate the idea of functional programming since cumulative is a side effect of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`_.reduce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)

```js
return _.reduce(
    array
    , (acc, _) => { 
        acc.push(_ + acc.slice(-1)[0])    // adding previous to current
        return acc
    }
    , [0]                                 // init acc with 0
).slice(1)                                // loose 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pure function without mutation with ES6 syntax

If you are looking for a function with pure functionnal programming, here is another option using lodash reduce function:

Feel free to edit the returned value if the array is empty.

### Function

```js
const sumCum = (numbers: Array<number>) =>
  numbers.length === 0
    ? 'Returned value if array is empty'
    : _.reduce(
        numbers,
        (final, current, index) =>
          index === 0 ? final : [...final, final[final.length - 1] + current],
        [numbers[0]]
      )
```

### Outputs (using Jest)

```js
describe('Maths', () => {
  test('sumCum', () => {
    expect(sumCum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).toEqual([1, 3, 6, 10, 15])
    expect(sumCum([])).toEqual('Returned value if array is empty')
    expect(sumCum([-1, -10, 20, -4])).toEqual([-1, -11, 9, 5])
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((c,i,a) => c + (a[i-1] || 0));

Comment: This produces `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` which is not correct

Comment: The correct answer would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((c,i,a) => c + (a.slice(0, i).reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0) || 0));`